# How to get ID of insert query in Room db with coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, coroutine

I want to get callback when insert data successfully in Roomdb with coroutine

MyDao.kt

```
@Dao
interface MyDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(obj: Task): Long
}
```

TaskViewModel.kt

```
class TaskViewModel(var context:Context) : ViewModel{
    private var appDao: AppDao

    init {
        val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(context)
        appDao = db.appDao()
    }

    fun insertTask(tast: Task) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
          val mID = appDao.insert(task)
        }
    }
}
```

How to return `mID` from `insertTask()` method ?

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap the call with the  `withContext` and mark the function as suspend

```kotlin
suspend insertTask(task: Task) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { appDao.insertTask(task) }
```

And from your view:

```kotlin
fun saveTask(t: Task) = lifecycleScope.launch {
    val id = viewModel.insertTask(t)
    Toast.makeText(context, "Task $id has been inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

You could also return a `LiveData` that triggers a callback when it's done:

```kotlin
fun insertTask(task: Task): LiveData<Long> {
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<Long>()
    viewModelScope.launch {
        liveData.value = dao.insertTask(task)
    }
    return liveData
}
```

*Further advice*

Don't keep a reference to a context in your viewmodel. If you need the context use `AndroidViewModel` and `AndroidViewModel#getApplication()`

Comment: Thank you for answer. I accept and up vote but i dont want to call write  lifecycleScope.launch{} in every time from view , then how to do  ?

Comment: From view i just want to call like this  val id = viewModel.insertTask(t) then what i need to do ?  @Some random IT boy

Comment: The operation `val id = viewModel.insertTask(t)` I believe is impossible to perform by not calling `launch` or similar. To call a `suspend fun` you must be inside a `CoroutineScope` or inside another `suspend fun`. If you strictly want to avoid writing `lifecycleScope.launch` you may return a `LiveData` and observe it to get notified when the coroutine finishes its work like I have stated. This way you don't block the MainThread on Android. If, on the other side, want to block the MainThread you may call `runBlocking {}`, but this defeats the whole purpose of inserting in the background thread

Comment: If you just want to avoid `lifecycleScope.launch{}` you can write the following kotlin extension function that wraps the launch for you:
```fun Fragment.launch(coroutine: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit) = lifecycleScope.launch(coroutine)```. So you would be able to call it from any `Fragment` like `fun doSomething(): = launch { /*your coroutine code goes here*/} `

Comment: You can see in `TaskViewModel`  i use  `CoroutineScope`  but when i want to call that method from Fragment then i dont want to use `launch` or something, From there I just want to call like  `val id = viewModel.insertTask(t)'

Comment: The problem is that the MainThread and the GlobalScope don't share an execution context so you must either pass a callback through the `TaskViewModel#insertTask`, use the observable pattern or call launch from the `Fragment`. So you could do:

`fun insertTask(task: Task, callback: (Long) -> Unit) {
       GlobalScope.launch {
             val id = dao.insert(task)
             callback.invoke(id)
       }
}`

Comment: Also, avoid using the `GlobalScope`; using the `viewModelScope` ktx ensures that the coroutines are cancelled upon `ViewModel#onCleared` is called and so you are not leaking any Coroutines